# How audio can be added to a drum machine in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing FCC drum machine project in React and trying to add audio on the buttons, but could not add the sound. Can someone check that where I am making a mistake. Help is extremely appreciated.

### React:

```
class App extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {  
    super(props);
      this.state = {    
         drumPads : [   
          {  
            id: "Q",  
            src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3",
            beat: "Heater-1",
          },
          {
            id: "W",
            src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3",
            beat: "Heater-2"
          },
    }     

 handleClick(id, beat) {
     return () => {
        document.getElementById(id).play();
        this.setState({
          beatName: beat,
         });
     };
  }

  render() {
      return (
        this.state.drumPads.map((button, i) =>
        <button key={i} id={beat} onClick={this.handleClick(id, beat)}>
             <h1>{ button.id }</h1>
             <audio src={button.src} />
        </button>
       )
    )
   }
 }

  ReactDOM.render( <App />,
     document.getElementById("root")
   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this part of the code: `id={beat}` because you're just creating two buttons with the same id. What you mean to do is `id={button.beat}`. Check if that works.

Comment: Also, I'm not quite sure that your `handleClick` function is receiving any arguments. because `id` isn't defined and neither is `beat`

Comment: I haven't actually tested the code. This is from observation

Comment: i also modified handleClick as {this.handleClick(button.id, button.beat)}. I was able to get buttons, but still no sound.

Comment: Again, without testing, I think there shouldn't be a return in your handleClick function. Also, `beatname` is not a property of the state. Also, your `.play()` function is on the button and not the audio element.

Comment: I was able to do it. The corrected version:                                                     
    <button key={i}  onClick={this.handleClick(button.id, button.beat)}>            
             <h1>{ button.id }</h1>
            <audio id={button.id} src={button.src} />
     </button>

Comment: yeah, now your handleClick selects the audio element and plays it. Problem solved